# How to pass and compare arguments from one screen to another in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass these screen arguments from one page to another (group) and compare them in the other page.

```
IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                     
                    icon: Image.asset("assets/images/Grupos.png"),
                    iconSize: 80,
                    onPressed: () {  Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              Routes.group,
              arguments: ScreenArguments(args.id, args.name, args.value)
            );        
  })
```

I use that like this in the other page and make a method called Fate1() which compares args2.id with another set of data that I have.

```
class _GroupPageState extends State<GroupPage> {

  int widgetActivated = 0;
  
  Data _data = new Data();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final args2 = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
    
  List<double> Fate1(){
      List<double> listaDeValues = [];
for ( int i = 0; i < _data.getLength(); i++){
    if (args2.id == _data.getId(i) ){

      listaDeValues = _data.getValues(i);
return listaDeValues;
     
    }
     }
    return   listaDeValues;
    }
```

And I use the Fate1() method like this in the same class:

```
Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index,) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
     double value1 = Fate1()[index];
 
  
   
    return InkWell(
    child:   CardWidget(
              gauge: AnimatedRadialGauge1(context, value1, 50, 180, 10  ),
```

The problem is Fate1() can't be called inside the widget _itembuilder because it is only declared inside the widget build not the class itself. And I can't declare it inside the class itself because I use the args2 variable which uses "context" like this `final args2 = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;` I wonder how to make the Fate1() method usable in the _itemBuilder widget? Or is there another way? Thanks!

I have tried using chatgpt but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to initiate args2 in initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    args2 = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
  }
```

and declare in the class itself

```
late ScreenArguments args2;
```

args2 should be accessible in all the class